# Is there Salesforce documentation on RestResource Object?

Tags: documentation, restresource

I'm following a design pattern set by one of our devs.

```
    RestResource.RequestBody requestBody = RestResource.getRequestBody();
```

I'm trying to find documentation on this object, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. Is this design pattern outdated?

Should we be using something like RestContext instead?

### Apex class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/endpoint')
global without sharing class myRestClass {
    @HttpPost
    global static void create() {

        RestResource.RequestBody requestBody = RestResource.getRequestBody();
        //Call your caller class

        System.debug(requestBody.body);
        myProcessingClass mp = new myProcessingClass(requestBody.body);

        //Check response
        System.debug('trying to process');
        mp.processActivity();

        RestResource.getResponse('SUCCESS', 201);


    }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot of Documentation on System Namespace]

Comment: Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_restrequest.htm

Comment: Thanks, I've read this page but was curious about the RestResource.RequestBody method. It doesn't seem to be anywhere.

Comment: RestResource is an annotation that is used at the class level and enables you to expose an Apex class as a REST resource. It is not an object.

Comment: For me I feel that you wanted `RestContext.response` instead of `RestResource.getRequestBody()`. Are you sure?

Comment: @JefersonChaves that is kind of my question. This current implementation is working, but there is little documentation on why it works i.e. nothing on the getRequestBody()  method. I was thinking that RestContext.response would make more sense as well.

Comment: @JefersonChaves is this how you guys set up webhooks in your implmentations RestContext.response instead of RestResource.getRequestBody()?

Comment: What is the API version of the implementation you have @thinker? Maybe that is what we need to look at. Could you post some portion of the code you have?

Comment: @JefersonChaves we are working with the version 48.0. Looking at the class that implemented this it was on version 41.0

Comment: Sounds like the developer created RestResource as a (custom) Apex class.

Comment: @identigral doesn't look like it's a custom apex class. Just did a quick git grep. Posting my code sample to discuss.

Comment: @JefersonChaves added the code. Anyone else who has suggestions or how this would get changed to sue the restcontext vars. Appreciate it. Want to make sure I'm using the most current gen.

Comment: @identigral you are correct. During the apex tests I was debugging and it showed up. Thank you for your insight. Post your answer to receive credit.